# Regex for finding 3 or more occurrences

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match 3 or more occurances of any repeating sub string, of more than 1 character, within a string, using regex?

For example:

The string `ABCD  ABC  AB ACD DE` has the sub-string `AB` 3 or more times.

The letter D also appears 3 times, but it is only one character, so this is not to be matched.

I'm thinking this is beyond the limits of regex, but in case there is some genius out there, I will pose the question just the same.

What I'm trying to do is reduce the size of encrypted query strings by replacing repeated character sequences with one character, but the string needs to have a "legend" appended (or prepended) to it to indicate what has been reduced.

For example:

The string `ABCD  ABC  AB ACD DE` would be changed to something like `.CD  .C  . ACD DE` and something needs to be added to it so that it is known that . now represents AB.

Something like `.AB-`

where the `-` acts as a terminator. So replacing less than 3 would actually increase the size of the overall string.

I'm using Classic ASP, but I'm quite happy for a C# solution.  I can then stick that in a dll and use it that way.

Comment: Which tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: Language I'm using is classic ASP

Comment: Is this .NET regular expression?

Comment: @Graham. You mean ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many restrictions here due to regex's greediness and consumption of characters as it goes along the string.  Namely, you will only be able to match the one result that most satiates the regex's greediness

```
(..+).*\1.*\1
```

The above captures at least two characters and will match if that same substring exists twice later on.  This works for

```
ABCD ABC AB ACD DE
ABCD ABCD AB ABCD DE
```

However in the latter case only "ABCD" gets matched; AB does not.

Unless this is good enough for you, I would recommend using a solution other than regex such as splitting the words by spaces and inspecting each.  It will probably end up being more efficient than the regex too.

Comment: It is possible to modify the regex to find `BCD`, but not `ABC`. If the string is longer, suffix array is one solution.